# Using jquery to set / unset boolean attributes the HTML5 way

Tags: php, jquery, html, xhtml

I wrote lots of code following XHTML rules, so I have things like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Field1" disabled="disabled">
<input type="text" name="Field2" readonly="readonly">
```

Thanks God, HTML5 went back to the old days where we could just do this:

```
<input type="text" name="Field1" disabled>
<input type="text" name="Field2" readonly>
```

However, how can I use jQuery to set or unset these boolean attributes? I always used `.attr("readonly", "readonly")`, but it generates the older XHTML syntax. I want my code to be the HTML5 way, with just "readonly", or just "disabled".

By the way, using `.prop()` won't work for me, I need to really change the attributes on my markup, because I have CSS rules depending on these attributes. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#inputId').attr('readonly', true);
```

I think you can also do...

```
$("#inputId").prop("readonly",true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but even setting it to true, the generated code is readonly = "readonly". I'm testing on Chrome. And using prop() doesn't change the markup on the document, so my CSS won't "see" it. Besides, when using prop, you have to use readOnly (capital O).

Comment: It's just for code uniformity. I'm using jQuery in so many places in my code, that I thought it would be weird to mix different approaches. Just that, there's not any stronger reason.

Comment: I guess what I mean, is that why don't you just use php to set that data?

Comment: Because I use ajax to change the input value, and while it's gathering the data, I use javascript / jQuery to keep the input in readonly state. And my CSS turns the field gray when it's in this state.

Comment: Ah I see.....well honestly, and this is just me, but I don't think I  would even care if its not perfect HTML5 or whatever....as long as it works, then who cares....you're likely the only one to see or care about the code anyways. ;)

Comment: LOL, indeed, sometimes I feel like this! I try to follow all standards to the detail, but I may be getting too far this time! Well, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @KyleK the fun thing about HTML5 is that lots of things are valid. `disabled` is just as "perfect" as `disabled=""` and `disabled="disabled"`, and you can choose.

Comment: @Mr Lister, indeed, it's already dragging lots and lots of compatibility legacy stuff from previous versions, and most importantly, it's dragging the weird standards XHTML introduced, which miserably failed. The disable="disable" is, perhaps, the best example of how weird that thing was!